# Rails activerecord joins update_all attribute of joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, sql-update

I have the following relations:

reservation.rb

```
has_many :room_requests, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :reservation
accepts_nested_attributes_for :room_requests, allow_destroy: true
has_many :rooms, through: :room_requests
```

room_request.rb

```
belongs_to :reservation
belongs_to :room
```

room.rb

```
has_many :room_requests
has_many :reservations, through: :room_requests
```

And I'm trying update the attribute 'status' from rooms that belong to certain reservations. Something like:

```
Reservation.joins(:rooms).update_all('rooms.status': 'to_clean')
```

But evidently it doesn't work like this. I want to do it in a single query  but I can't quite grasp it. What am I missing?

Comment: where is `checked_in` relation?

Comment: checked_in is just a scope filter. It's the same as .where(status: 'checked_in')

Comment: is it scope of reservation model?

Comment: It actualy does this: Reservation.public_send(filter) where filter in this case is 'cheked_in'

Comment: seems that is in room model

Comment: well try: `Reservation.rooms.checked_in.update_all('rooms.status': 'to_clean')`?

Comment: or event explicitly: `Reservation.rooms.where(rooms: { status: 'checked.in' }).update_all('rooms.status': 'to_clean')`

Comment: Sory, but the check_in thing is related to the reservation, not the room. Maybe it was confusing, I'll remove it from the question

Comment: it does not matter: try: Reservation.rooms.where(rooms: { status: 'checked_in' }).update_all('rooms.status': 'to_clean')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I couldn't do the query that way because what I needed to update was on the Room model, and the query was being done in the Reservation model. I needed to reverse it, and came up with this:

```
Room.where(id: RoomRequest.where(reservation: Reservation.checked_in).select(:room_id)).update_all(status: Room.statuses[:to_clean])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should link your Reservations model also with Rooms via a has_many, through: room_requests..

Once done you can easily go with:

```
Reservations.rooms.status.update_all('rooms.status': 'to_clean')
```

However, make sure that your room_requests are available and that reservations are thus assigned to rooms via the room_requests.

Cheers,
T

Comment: I forgot to add that line but it was already there. Your solution is not working despite having that line added.